# Join table on serialized array field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I fetch a serialized array from MySQL database with the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT own_addressbooks 
            FROM users_modules
            WHERE user = ? 
            AND own_addressbooks <> ?";
//result : a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}
```

from the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_modules` (
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `own_groups` text NOT NULL,
  `read_groups` text NOT NULL,
  `modify_groups` text NOT NULL,
  `own_mails` text NOT NULL,
  `read_mails` text NOT NULL,
  `own_calendars` text NOT NULL,
  `modify_calendars` text NOT NULL,
  `read_calendars` text NOT NULL,
  `own_addressbooks` text,
  `modify_addressbook` text NOT NULL,
  `read_addressbooks` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Unserializing the array i get:

```
 array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Where every field of the array is a row into the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `addressbooks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `entries` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Is there, through a join query, a way to obtain the title of each addressbook? Or by the way, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: You should really instead add a `user_id` to the `addressbooks` table that tells who owns the address book, and skip the serialized "own_addressbooks" entirely. That way you can join and find out all address books a user owns. If an address books can be owned by multiple users, you'll need an extra table to associate them.

Comment: Uhm, what will happen if i have 10000 addressbooks? I don't think is goo, in terms of performances, to check 9000 records to find an addressbook stored at the row number 9001...

Comment: With correct indexing on the database, an SQL search for a single row it should still be _much_ faster than shipping all data to PHP, deserializing, searching and sending another query round trip to the database to get the actual row. That said, if you fetch all rows to PHP to compare them instead of using SQL to search, you won't gain much.

Comment: Well, i'll check for this. Thank you!